# sudo asking for password even though user doesn't have a password set

Tags: terminal, security, password, sudo

I have a computer that doesn't not require a password. I'd like this to continue into `sudo`, but unfortunately it doesn't recognise a user not having a password.

According to Apple the `sudo` command requires a non-blank password: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202035

Is there some way I can easily override this so I can have a blank password with `sudo`? It's only ever a hindrance and security on this machine is not an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer that works perfectly (although it requires temporarily adding a password to your user first):

1. Open the Terminal

   Type: `sudo visudo`

   Enter your user's password (create one if necessary).
2. Change this line FROM:

   `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL`

   TO:

   `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

   (press 'i' to enter insert mode if you can't edit the text)
3. Write and Quit

   `:wq`

   (press 'esc' first to enter command mode)

Comment: Just a note. If you need to enter many commands which require the sudo prefix, enter `sudo sh` first. This will leave you logged in as the root user until you enter the `exit` command. As root user, the `sudo` prefix is implicit.